# Which freewheel/cassette does a stock Kent Seachange have?

Tags: road-bike, repair, cassette, freewheel

No, I did not buy the wrong remover tool! Stop laughing!

Answer (score 2):

In looking for the specs for the Kent Seachange - with the thought that maybe the type of freewheel would be listed - I found that the [Kent Seachange](https://kent.bike/search?type=product,page&q=seachange*) is a coaster brake bike and does not have a freewheel.

You don't need a remover tool for this bike

[image]

If this is not your bike then please post pictures of your freewheel.

Comment: Ah. Well, that would explain it, wouldn't it!